# Conditional prop in interface based on generic

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I have an API which returns the following shapes;

```json
// requests which don't return any data: <ApiResponseSuccess>
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "updated",
}

// requests which return data: <ApiResponseSuccess<User[]>>
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "retrieved",
  "data": [user1, user2, user3, ...] 
}

// requests which failed: <ApiResponseFailure>
{
  "success": false,
  "message": "some failure message"
}
```

Which I've typed using the following types

```js
interface ApiResponseBase {
  success: boolean;
  message: string;
}

// This will only have a data prop if a type is specified for it
export type ApiResponseSuccess<T = never> = ApiResponseBase & {
  success: true;
} & ([T] extends [never] ? { data?: never } : { data: T });

interface ApiResponseFailure extends ApiResponseBase {
  success: false;
}

export type ApiResponse<T = never> = ApiResponseSuccess<T> | ApiResponseFailure;
```

which works fine for the most part, when I can explicitly specify the value of the generic type param passed to the `ApiResponse` type eg with this basic data fetch fn

```js
const getUsers = async (): Promise<ApiResponse<User[]>> => {
  try {
    const users = await db.users.findMany();
    return {
       success: true,
       message: `retrieved ${users.length} users`,
       data: users
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      success: false,
      message: "failed to get users"
    }
  }
}
```

here, I can be confident of the type of the data property

```js
  const userResult = await getUsers();
  if(userResult.success){
    // here, userResult.data is correctly typed as User[]
    doSomething(userResult.data)
  }
```

In this update function T is defaulted to `never` as no data is returned - this also works fine

```js
const updateUser = async (id: string, partialUser: Partial<User>): Promise<ApiResponse> => {
  try {
    await db.users.updateOne({
      where: {id},
      data: partialUser
    });
    return {
       success: true,
       message: `updated user`
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      success: false,
      message: "failed to update user"
    }
  }

}
```

However if I'm using the interface in a function which passes the value of T down from it's own generic type param then I run into trouble

```js
/**
 * Express body validation wrapped middleware
 * sets validated body in res.locals.body if validation was successful
 * or passes the request to the error handler if it was not
 * @param schema the joi schema to validate the body against
 * @returns express middleware function
 */
export const validateBody = <T>(
  schema: Joi.Schema
): ((
  req: express.Request,
  res: ExpressResponse<T>,
  next: express.NextFunction
) => Promise<void>) => {
  return async (req, res: ExpressResponse<T>, next) => {
    // validate body and return on failure
    const validationResult = validateRequest<T>(req.body, schema);

    if (!validationResult.success) {
      const err = new HttpException(400, "Bad Request");
      // will be handled by express errorHandler fn
      // will not proceed to route handler
      next(err);
    }

    if (validationResult.success) {
      // annoyingly typescript can't deduce that T will not be never and that
      // data will definitely be T so it has to be cast here
      res.locals.body = validationResult.data;
      // no error is passed so will proceed to route handler
      next();
    }
  };
};
```

in this function, because `validateRequest<T>` returns `<ApiResponse<T>>`, and as T could be anything, including `never`, the response from `validateRequest` ends up being typed as

```js
{
  success: boolean;
  message: string;
  data: T | undefined;
}
```

so I have to cast `data as T` which feels like I'm cheating. Is there a way I can specify that `validateBody<T DOES NOT EXTEND never>`, and throw a complier error if the method is used without a type param, or a type param that is `never`? If I were able to do that, would typescript then be able to infer that the data prop should be `T` rather than `T | undefined`?

Is there a better way of handling the two successful types - one with data and one without? I'd be grateful for any advice!

Comment: I'm usually using discriminated union for response type. See [example](https://tsplay.dev/WYBOQw)

Comment: Please consider providing reproducible example

Comment: yeah - sorry this is too wordy - I'll get an example in the playground